# How does my Visual Studio program reference the correct database file?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite

I have a C# application that creates an installer with a Setup project in Visual Studio. It all works fine except for the SQLite database that I am trying to include.

What I have done:

- Added the database file from my solution to the Application Folder of the Setup project.
- Stored the connection string in my code where I use it to create the connection.

  ```
     private const string conString = "DATASOURCE = HCATDatabase.sqlite; VERSION = 3;";
     SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(conString);`
  ```
- Rebuilt the Setup project and the Solution.
- Installed the program from the created installation.

What happened when I fired the installed application:

- The database gives errors like "No such table", while the database in my solution does have these tables.
- The application shows data that is not in the database from my solution.

I compared the database files with DB Browser (the one from my project that I included in my Setup project and the one in the installed program's file) and they are identical.

So somehow the program uses a different (third) database file.

How can I find out where the program gets this file from and how can I change it to use the proper file?

**UPDATE:** I have found thanks to @Roger Lipscombe that the program uses a database file in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\ProgramCompany\MyProgram.

**UPDATE 2:** I deleted the folders (that were pretty old) in the above directory and that fixed everything, the program now references the correct database. **I would love it if someone could explain all of this.**

Comment: Use Process Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to find out what files your application has open. That will show you the full path to the database file that it *actually* has open.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thanks for that, I have updated my question from what I have found

Comment: The problem is in your application itself, not Visual Studio or Windows.  You tried to save data into `Program Files`, where it's expressly forbidden to do so since Windows 95. That prevents badly coded applications from deleting executable files for example. Previous Windows versions (before Win 7 at least) would prevent you from doing so with a security error. Later versions redirect the writes to the correct place, the user's data folder

Comment: The correct place to store user documents is in the user's `My Documents` folder. The correct place to store application data is in the user's data folder, in an application-specific folder (eg `MyCompany\MyApp\...`). You can get the correct folder with `Environment.GetFolderPath` ,eg `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the explanation, this must have happened a while ago while I was testing out the setup project. Deleting the files helped (the program references the database file in my program's folder in program files instead of the one in appdata). I just don't understand why.